# what is the cardinality of minimum vertex cover in the complete graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have a complete graph with n vertex. The **MinimumVertexCover** of the complete graph is **n-1**.Can I take less then **n-1** as a **MinimumVertexCover**? If the answer is **No** please Explain it with the proof?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math, not programming.

Comment: You can see this question [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639977/size-of-minimum-vertex-cover-on-complete-graph)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is No.

I think the easiest way to prove it is by Gallai’s result. Recall that an independent set of vertices is one in which two vertices share an edge. Now Gallai’s theorem says that:

α(G)+β(G)=n

where,

α(G)=
size of largest independent set,
β(G)=size of minimum vertex cover, and
n=

number of vertices in G.

Now clearly α(Kn)=1
since a set of two vertices in Kn is not independent. It follows therefore that β(G)=n−1, as required.